# List when sent to Controller from GSP is a String?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a List of Strings built using Javascript on the client side which looks like this in the Javascript console:

```
["No address provided.", "No telephone number provided."]
```

I send this to my Controller as one of the params from my GSP in an ajax call but the controller sees it like this:

```
No address provided.,No telephone number provided.
```

i.e. as a String (without square brackets). This is how I am sending my params:

```
<button id="save" onclick = "${remoteFunction(controller: 'customer', 
                                                action: 'saveModifiedIndividualRecord',
                                                params: '\'uniqueId=\' + uniqueId + \'&secondaryId=\' + secondaryId + \'&redIssuesRemoved=\' + removedRedIssues + \'&yellowIssuesRemoved=\' + removedYellowIssues')}"> Save </button>
```

Any way so that the Controller will see it as a List and not a String?

Comment: What is the name of the param that you provided the example output for (I'm assuming its either redIssuesRemoved or yellowIssuesRemoved or both...).

Comment: You could try using join: ... `+ \'&redIssuesRemoved=\' + join(removedRedIssues, '&redIssuesRemoved=') + `... so that the array is sent to the controller with something looking like: `saveModifiedIndividualRecord?redIssuesRemoved='No address provided.'&redIssuesRemoved='No telephone number provided.'&...` This is the usual way of sending array values via GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
def redIssuesRemoved = params.redIssuesRemoved.tokenize(",")
def yellowIssuesRemoved = params.yellowIssuesRemoved.tokenize(",")
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that this will break if there is an internal comma in one of your JS array (String) values.

Answer (score 1):

Am guessing both red or yellow issues are you list of string params.
So Try def listOfRedIssue =  params.list('redIssuesRemoved')  .. this makes it as List or yellowIssues

Comment: This works but puts both issues as only one String in the list like this: [No address provided., No telephone number provided.]. But these should be two separate Strings in the list.

Comment: You need to first send the 2 issues as a list - you are currently sending them as a single string! To send an array via HTTP GET you need to make sure there are 2 instances of the param specified: one for each instance of the the array (see my comment on the Q). Then this answer will work.